# Applescript: Make new folder structure in multiple folders

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

This code for an applet creates a specific folder structure inside of either a single selected folder or whatever the open folder is in Finder when the applet is clicked. It breaks down if multiple folders are selected. Is there a way to get this script to work when multiple folders are selected?

```
property archivesFolder : "Archives"

property imagesFolder : "Images"

property proofreadFolder : "Proofreading"

property proofFolder : "Proofs"

property sourceFolder : "Source"

try
    tell application "Finder" to set theLocation to the selection as alias
on error
    tell application "Finder" to set theLocation to (folder of the front window as alias)
end try

tell application "Finder"

    if not (exists folder archivesFolder of theLocation) then
        make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:archivesFolder}
    end if

    if not (exists folder imagesFolder of theLocation) then
        make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:imagesFolder}
    end if

    if not (exists folder proofreadFolder of theLocation) then
        make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:proofreadFolder}
    end if

    if not (exists folder proofFolder of theLocation) then
        make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:proofFolder}
    end if

    if not (exists folder sourceFolder of theLocation) then
        make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:sourceFolder}
    end if

end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
property folderNames : {"Archives", "Images", "Proofreading", "Proofs", "Source"}

tell application "Finder"
set selectedFolders to selection
if (count of selectedFolders) > 0 then
    repeat with aFolder in selectedFolders
        set theLocation to aFolder as string
        repeat with newFolder in folderNames
            try
                make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:"" & newFolder & ""}
            end try
        end repeat
    end repeat
else
    set theLocation to (target of front window) as string
    repeat with newFolder in folderNames
        try
            make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:"" & newFolder & ""}
        end try
    end repeat
end if
end tell
```

Comment: Works great, but loses the functionality of creating those folders in the current Finder window if nothing is selected.

Comment: @fanaugen Does the posted answer not work? Can you help me replicate an error?

Comment: @adayzdone The code you posted works fine. I was just replying to user1231499's comment to restore the feature of taking the folder which is open in the current Finder window as default when nothing is selected.

Comment: Doesn't | if (count of selectedFolders) > 0 then | else | set theLocation to (target of front window) as string | accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Works like a charm now. Thank you both very much for your help!